# Global variable is defined inside <script> tag. But it is overwritten when accessed outside <script> tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, ejs

I'm trying to access Facebook SDK inside HTML.

I have a global variable `accessToken`. The value of this variable will be generated inside the SDK. The SDK is included in the ejs file inside `<script>` tags.

**My EJS code:**

```
<body>
<!--------------------- Facebook SDK script Starts --------------------->
<%      var accessToken;   %>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '****',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.11'
    });


FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
});

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   function statusChangeCallback(response){

    if (response.status === 'connected'){
        accessToken= response.authResponse.accessToken;
    console.log("User Logged in. Access Token: " + accessToken);  

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Not logged into FB");  
    };

    }


function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}

</script>
<!--=============== Facebook SDK script ends =============== -->

<fb:login-button 
  scope="public_profile,email,user_friends"
  onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
<h1>Click here to log into FB: </h1>
<form action="/checkdp" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="accessToken" value="<%=accessToken%>"> 
    <button>Click Here</button>
</form>

</body>
```

As you may have noticed, I introduced `var accessToken` with null value outside the `<script>` tags and defined its value inside the `<script>` tags.

**Adding the code again:**

```
    if (response.status === 'connected'){
        accessToken= response.authResponse.accessToken;
    console.log("User Logged in. Access Token: " + accessToken);
```

I console logged the value and it prints perfectly. But when I accessed the variable again inside the HTML form, the variable value `= ""` (null).

It seems like the value that is assigned inside the `<script>` tags is overwritten once it is outside the `<script>` tags.

A developer I asked said it is asynchronous or something like that. I didn't understand that so I couldn't get further help from him.

**Question:** Anybody want to give a try?

Comment: I also tried removing the <scripts> tag completely and replaced them all with <% %> tags since it is ejs file. But that is throwing an error like ";" missing. Can't find where it is missing though. Because the same code works perfect when it is inside <script> tag.

Comment: Please change "Question: Anybody want to give a try?" as "Appreciate any help" which was there in my original post. The question alone sounds a bit harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the hidden input field appears to be assigned during page load while parsing the HTML. The value of `accessToken` at this time will still be  `undefined`.

Try setting the value of the input element after the access token has been retrieved:

```
if (response.status === 'connected'){
    accessToken= response.authResponse.accessToken;
    document.querySelect( "[name=accessToken]").value = accessToken;
    console.log("User Logged in. Access Token: " + accessToken);
```

(Untested).

Comment: Awesome!! It worked just as perfect!!! No words to define my happiness. Been trying to accomplish this for three days now! Thanks a ton!!